# Left-aligning LaTeX Bibliography Display

Tags: bibliographies, horizontal-alignment

I have problem on how to make the bibliography item left-aligned. My current bibliography output is below.

[image: sample output]

As  you can see, the reference item code is currently right-aligned, and I need it to be left-aligned. Any idea on how to achieve that?

My current code for the bibliography is

```
\usepackage{natbib}
%....
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{references}
```

Thank you.

**update**

Below is the code after i reduce many of it. The problem still occur on this code. I use MiKTeX 2.9.

```
\documentclass[bahasa, 12pt, a4paper, final]{report}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}


\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \bibliographystyle{alpha}
    \bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which document class are you using? The standard behaviour (at least in `book`, `report`, and `article`) is for the labels to be left aligned, so there must be something else in your document. Can yo please add a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) to your question illustrating the mentioned behaviour?

Comment: I just updated with the minimal working example. (hope it's minimal enough)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put this in your document preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{[#1]\hfill}
\makeatother
```

Comment: It really works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the alpha bibliography style. If you use natbib, I recommend you switch the bibliography style to `plainnat`:

```
\documentclass[bahasa, 12pt, a4paper, final]{report}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[options]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

You can find more useful *options* for natbib package in 
[Reference sheet for natbib usage.](http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php) As example, author-year citations are default. If you want numerical citations you can use `numbers` as option.

Comment: @Petra I exposed the right way. **alpha** style is not part of _natbib_, and plainnat do what you were looking. But, if you prefer some magic commands. OK!