# BibTeX key alignment and localization

Tags: horizontal-alignment, bibtex, languages

I'm having problems with my `bibtex` keys. According to my style guide, they should be left-aligned, whereas now they're right-aligned. Is there a way to change that? I am using `amsalpha` bibliography style.

[image: right-aligned bibliography keys]

Also, in the authors list, I need to have a localized value of `'and'` before the last author. I've found a bunch of `bibtex` localization files in it's installation directory. Will I need to copy one and change strings in it? How do I tell `bibtex` which one to use (I'm using XeLaTeX for my document)?

Removing the `'and'` completely and just leaving the comma before it will do too. I do not need a good solution to this one right now, a quick one will suffice.

*EDIT*
Ok, i managed to figure out the right alignment of keys is cause by `natbib` package. I include MWE below:

`mwe.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}

\begin{document}

\cite{hu62}
\cite{ss97}
\cite{crm03}

\bibliography{mwe}

\end{document}
```

`mwe.bib`:

```
@Article{hu62,
    title = {Visual Pattern Recognition by Moment Invariants},
    journal = {IRE Transactions on Information Theory},
    pages = {179--187},
    year = {1962},
    author = {Hu, Ming-Kuei}
}

@Conference{ss97,
    title = {Hu’s moment invariants: How invariant are they under skew and perspective transformations?},
    booktitle = {IEEE WESCANEX 97: Communications, Power and Computing. Conference Proceedings.},
    pages = {292--295},
    year = {1997},
    author = {Sivaramakrishna, Radhika and Shashidhar, N. S.}
}

@Article{crm03,
    title = {A comparative analysis of algorithms for fast computation of Zernike moments},
    journal = {Pattern Recognition},
    pages = {731--742},
    year = {2003},
    author = {Chong, Chee-Way and Raveendran, P. and Mukundan, R.}
}
```

I am using `bibtex` and `xelatex`.

Comment: In biblatex, look for `finalnamedelim` (also `\finalnamecomma`).  (Sorry, I can't easily answer the first question since I've never used such a style, or looked into its implementation.)

Comment: Do you mean `biblatex` or BibTeX? `biblatex` doesn't have a style `amsalpha`. Please provide a minimal example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try `babelbib`; I've adapted your example to Italian and I get "e" instead of "and".

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mwe.bib}
@Article{hu62,
    title = {Visual Pattern Recognition by Moment Invariants},
    journal = {IRE Transactions on Information Theory},
    pages = {179--187},
    year = {1962},
    author = {Hu, Ming-Kuei}
}

@Conference{ss97,
    title = {Hu's moment invariants: How invariant are they under skew and perspective transformations?},
    booktitle = {IEEE WESCANEX 97: Communications, Power and Computing. Conference Proceedings.},
    pages = {292--295},
    year = {1997},
    author = {Sivaramakrishna, Radhika and Shashidhar, N. S.}
}

@Article{crm03,
    title = {A comparative analysis of algorithms for fast computation of Zernike moments},
    journal = {Pattern Recognition},
    pages = {731--742},
    year = {2003},
    author = {Chong, Chee-Way and Raveendran, P. and Mukundan, R.}
}\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[italian]{babelbib}

\bibliographystyle{babalpha}

\begin{document}

\cite{hu62}
\cite{ss97}
\cite{crm03}

\bibliography{mwe}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Hyphenation is incorrect, though. Check `babelbib` documentation.

Comment: You might be right, but babelbib doesn't have the language I need (lithuanian) and your new mwe doesn't use natbib. Nevertheless, your answer is much cleaner, so I will accept it, even though I will probably be using my own method until I find something else. Thank you.

Comment: @guilty Unfortunately there's no support for Lithuanian, but the `.bdf` file that `babelbib` uses is just a list of keywords and it shouldn't be too difficult to write one for your language.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found solutions to both of my problems.

Keys can be made left-aligned with following code in your preamble or style file ([source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21309/15703)):

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{[#1]\hfill}
\makeatother
```

For the last delimiter problem, I had to edit `amsalpha.bst` file, which I found under `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/amscls` in my machine (make sure to do a **backup**).

Specific changes:

1. Line 351 `{ "," * }` to `{ "" *}`. This removes the comma before the last author.
2. Line 356 `{ " and " * t * }` to `{ " ir " * t * }`, where `ir` is a localized value of `and`, of course. Mind the spaces.

It is not the prettiest solution, but i don't think there's another one. As you might notice, the strings in `amsalpha.bst` are hardcoded, so the only way to change them is by hand. I would be happy if anyone more experienced could confirm this.

These solutions work with

```
BibTeX 0.99d (TeX Live 2011)
kpathsea version 6.0.1
```