# Reference 1-9 need to flush more left keeping other unchanged

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I was writing a report using latex and got issues with the bibliography page margin. First [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/px2OF.jpg)-[9] references have more left margins than rest of the other margins. I am using report class with bibliography style "abbrv". I even tried "IEEEtr" style and nothing changed.

```
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{mybib}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The bibliography labels are simply right-aligned, and you'd like to have them left-aligned. This is easier to do with `biblatex`.

Comment: Just for the record, this isn't a mistake or a bug, but a conscious choice that they should be flush with the right 'margin' of the labels, otherwise you'd have an irregular gap between label and reference. Of course, if that's what you want, then that's what you want, but just so you know what's happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it corrected. The issue was with the bibliography labels. Labels left alignment in the references list can be corrected using these line of code for "abbrv", "IEEEtr" citation style. Similar question was answered for "alpha" style in 
[Left-aligning LaTeX Bibliography Display](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21308/left-aligning-latex-bibliography-display).

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{[#1]\hfill}
\makeatother
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for med to get all bibliography labels left-aligned (flush with the left margin) using "IEEEtran" after hours of searching. Great job!